# How to make propel build models with namespaces in the right directory?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, propel, autoload

Default directory for my classes is: app/

Composer autoload config is:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "App\\": "app/" }
    }
}
```

On propel's schema.xml my namespace is `"App\Models"`

```
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xsd.propelorm.org/1.6/database.xsd"
          namespace="App\Models"
        >
    <table name="user">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="email" type="varchar" size="255" required="true"/>
        <column name="password" type="varchar" size="60" required="true"/>
        <column name="country_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
        <column name="timezone" type="varchar" size="50" required="true"/>
        <foreign-key foreignTable="country">
            <reference local="country_id" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>

    <table name="country">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true"/>
    </table>
</database>
```

My propel.php.dist is:

```
<?php
return [
    'propel' => [
        'paths' => [
            // The directory where Propel expects to find your `schema.xml` file.
            'schemaDir' => 'database/schemas',

            // The directory where Propel should output generated object model classes.
            'phpDir' => 'app/Models'
        ]
    ]
];
```

When I execute `vendor/bin/propel model:build` the resulting structure is like this:

```
/app/
|___Models/
    |___App/
        |___Models/
            |___Base/
            |___Map/
            |___Country.php
            |___CountryQuery.php
            |___User.php
            |___UserQuery.php
```

I need the structure to be like this:

```
/app/
|___Models/
    |___Base/
    |___Map/
    |___Country.php
    |___CountryQuery.php
    |___User.php
    |___UserQuery.php
```

I tried every combination in this manual: [Database Attributes](http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/schema.html#database-attributes)

Is there a different way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration specified in the question looks correct, except for one thing that is missing, which made it work in my case: set namespaceAutoPackage to false. In the case of the question's php configuration file, that looks like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'propel' => [
        'paths' => [
            // The directory where Propel expects to find your `schema.xml` file.
            'schemaDir' => 'database/schemas',

            // The directory where Propel should output generated object model classes.
            'phpDir' => 'app/Models'
        ],
        'generator' => [
            'namespaceAutoPackage' => 'false'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to set generator.namespaceAutoPackage to "false". Then make sure you still have the paths.phpDir set to "app/Models" and in the schema.xml file, keep your database namespace setting to "App\Models".

http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#generator-settings

Answer (score 3):

You have to changue your database namespace in your schema.xml , you have to set the namespace to:

namespace="\app\Models"

Comment: Pay attencion to the "\" - the root namespace

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `build.properties` file.

You should have something similar to this:

```
propel.packageObjectModel               = true
propel.generator.targetPackage          = App\Models
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that works as requested:

composer.json

```
}
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["app/"]
    }
}
```

... tells Composer to autoload classes within this folder

propel.php.dist

```
<?php
return [
    'propel' => [
        'paths' => [
            // The directory where Propel expects to find your `schema.xml` file.
            'schemaDir' => 'database/schemas',

            // The directory where Propel should output generated object model classes.
            'phpDir' => 'app'
        ]
    ]
];
```

... tells Propel to put your model classes in the same folder (app) in which Composer will autoload

schema.xml

```
<database ... namespace="Models">
    ...
</database>
```

... tells Propel to use the `Models` namespace for all your models

Then you can use any model with

```
use \Models\Country;
new Country();
```